# Query to get updated Records from table if update exists or else get the new records

Tags: sql

I am trying to get records from table based on transaction id and update type. If my update type is 'U' for a transaction id fetch the record, else if there is no 'U' for a transaction fetch the records with update type 'N'

e.g:

```
Transaction_ID    Update_Type
1234                N
1234                U
5678                N
8756                N
```

Expected Output

```
Transaction_ID    Update_Type
1234                U
5678                N
8756                N
```

Comment: Hi, I need to use it on Spark SQL

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method using `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.update_type = 'U' or
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.Transaction_ID = t.Transaction_ID and
                        t2.update_type = 'U'
                 );
```

Or, you can use aggregation:

```
select Transaction_ID, max(update_type)
from t
group by Transaction_ID;
```